# ASP.NET MVC3: How do I ensure login before running controller code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I just want to ensure they are logged in before running any code.

I found User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Which can be used for boolean to check login. But if I did redirect, it would still run code, plus I would have to put it everywhere?

In ROR there was a before_filter option we did, that checked at the top of each controller, and wouldnt run it otherwise.

Please can someone guide me on how to do this.

Comment: Have you considered using the `<authorization>` elements in the web.config?

Comment: Are you doing straight ASP.NET or using MVC3?  Coming from ROR, MVC3 would likely be a good fit.

Comment: @Shawn: OP mentions "controller" in the question, so I assumed MVC.

Comment: @LukeH: Yeah, but he said it was a "controller" in Ruby on Rails, so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`AuthorizeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) for this:

> When you mark an action method with AuthorizeAttribute, access to that
>   action method is restricted to users who are both authenticated and
>   authorized. If you mark a controller with the attribute, all action
>   methods in the controller are restricted.
>
> The Authorize attribute lets you indicate that authorization is
>   restricted to predefined roles or to individual users. This gives you
>   a high degree of control over who is authorized to view any page on
>   the site.
>
> If an unauthorized user tries to access a method that is marked with
>   the Authorize attribute, the MVC framework returns a 401 HTTP status
>   code. If the site is configured to use ASP.NET forms authentication,
>   the 401 status code causes the browser to redirect the user to the
>   login page.

For example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent answers everyone. This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Your example only protects one method, not all methods in every controller. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx for a secure approach

Answer (score 2):

At the top of your controller class, write this :-

```
[Authorize]
public class StoreManagerController : Controller
```

Comment: Your example only protects one controller, not all methods in every controller. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx for a secure approach

Answer (score 2):

Use the Authorize Attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Your example only protects one method, not all methods in every controller. See my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx for a secure approach